# How to get Treeview DisclosureNode to right , in Javafx?

Tags: javafx, treeview, disclosure

In Javafx the DisclosureNode of Treeview is on left by default. How can I I place the Disclosure Node to Right (float right)..??
Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is DisclosureNode?

Comment: @UlukBiy It's the "expand/collapse" icon: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TreeCell.html#disclosureNodeProperty

Answer (score 1):

You only need to set the Node Orientation to get a right to left behaviour. But be aware of, that all childrens of this TreeView will inherit the orientation as a default.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.NodeOrientation;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TreeViewRightLeft extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TreeItem<String> item = new TreeItem<>("Root Node");
        item.setExpanded(true);
        item.getChildren().addAll(
                new TreeItem<>("Item 1"),
                new TreeItem<>("Item 2"),
                new TreeItem<>("Item 3")
        );
        TreeView<String> treeView = new TreeView<>(item);

        // Here you can select the orientation.
        treeView.setNodeOrientation(NodeOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(treeView);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
        primaryStage.setTitle("TreeView");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

#### Right to Left

[image: App]

#### Left to Right (default)

[image: AppDefault]

Comment: Hi, Is there any other way without using NodeOrientation. Can we do something with css..?

Comment: @user2396250 can you clarify why does not the node orientation fit for you?

Comment: @user2396250 Haven't seen such a CSS class. So probably the answer is No.